# Detecting duplicate combinations of integers of lists

Tags: python, combinations

*Please note: I have only started coding with Python since very recently and am not very acquainted with phrasing, so I do not have any idea on whether this question is a duplicate or not.*

I was trying to make my programme run quicker. Here is a portion of it:

```py
Die1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Die2 = (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)
Die3 = (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)
Die4 = (4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24)

success = 0
for n in range(1,101):
    for a1 in Die1:
        for a2 in Die2:
            for a3 in Die3:
                for a4 in Die4:
                    Q = [a1,a2,a3,a4,n]
                    success += flippo(Q)
print(round(success/1296,2),"% with", \
      Die1, Die2, Die3, Die4)
```

This programme takes four dice (each a list of 6 integers) as input, checks every single combination of those dice (129600 cases in total) and lastly gives the success rate as an output. `flippo(Q)` is my own function and takes the outcome of a roll of the four dice (`a1`,`a2`,`a3`, `a4`) and a number between 1 and 100 (`n`): a failure returns 0 and a success returns 1 after some algorithms. **The order which the outcomes of the dice (`a1`,`a2`,`a3`, `a4`) are in does not matter.** *On average, those algorithms took about 3.46ms each time, for a total of 449 seconds to check all 129600 cases.*

While this code works, it might be improved by skipping the algorithm `flippo(Q)` when `Q` is equivalent to one already covered. This would reduce the amount of times we would have to run `flippo(Q)`. I thought it would be possible to store all possible `Q`'s in a list and then detect duplicates, but such list would be way too big to handle efficiently. Furthermore, the duplicates being purged would still have to be counted towards the `success` count, meaning all *individual* results would have to be stored as well.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

*Edit: I defined `flippo(Q)` as follows:*

```py
def vereenvoudig(u):    ### Simplifies the fraction, given as [numerator,denominator]
    if u[1] < 0:        
        u[0] = -u[0]
        u[1] = -u[1]
    g = math.gcd(u[0],u[1])
    if g == 0:
        return ([0,0])
    else:
        return ([u[0]//g,u[1]//g])

def fplus(u,v): # Sum
    return [u[0]*v[1]+u[1]*v[0],u[1]*v[1]]

def fmin(u,v): # Difference
    return [u[0]*v[1]-u[1]*v[0],u[1]*v[1]]

def fmaal(u,v): # Product
    return [u[0]*v[0],u[1]*v[1]]

def fdeel(u,v): # Quotient
    return [u[0]*v[1],u[1]*v[0]]

def fop(u,v,op):
    if op == 0:
        return fmaal(u,v)
    if op == 1:
        return fplus(u,v)
    if op == 2:
        return fmin(u,v)
    if op == 3:
        return fdeel(u,v)

def flippo(Q): # return 1 if flippo is solvable, if not return 0
    a = Q[0]
    b = Q[1]
    c = Q[2]
    d = Q[3]
    r = Q[4]
    perms = permutations([a,b,c,d]) 
    lipe = list(perms)
    lipe.sort() 
    lipe=list(dict.fromkeys(lipe)) 
    for elt in lipe:
        for u1 in range(4):
            r1 = fop([elt[0],1],[elt[1],1],u1) 
            for u2 in range(4):
                r2a = fop([elt[2],1],r1,u2) 
                r2b = fop(r1,[elt[2],1],u2) 
                r2c = fop([elt[2],1],[elt[3],1],u2)
                for u3 in range(4): 
                    r3a = vereenvoudig(fop([elt[3],1],r2a,u3)) # 4 & [3&[1&2]]
                    if (r3a[0] == r) & (r3a[1] == 1): 
                        return 1
                    r3b = vereenvoudig(fop([elt[3],1],r2b,u3)) # 4 & [[1&2]&3]
                    if (r3b[0] == r) & (r3b[1] == 1):
                        return 1
                    r3c = vereenvoudig(fop(r2a,[elt[3],1],u3)) # [3&[1&2]] & 4
                    if (r3c[0] == r) & (r3c[1] == 1):
                        return 1
                    r3d = vereenvoudig(fop(r2b,[elt[3],1],u3)) # [[1&2]&3] & 4
                    if (r3d[0] == r) & (r3d[1] == 1):
                        return 1
                    r3e = vereenvoudig(fop(r1,r2c,u3)) # [1&2]&[3&4]
                    if (r3e[0] == r) & (r3e[1] == 1):
                        return 1
    return 0
```

*`flippo(Q)` calculates all possible operations between `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` and tries to find a solution to have `r` as a result.*

Comment: I recommend using `itertools.product` to get rid of nested loops, `for a1, a2, a3, a4 in product(Die1, Die2, Die3, Die4)`. See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's multiprocessing module and use multiple cores of your CPU.

```
import math
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool

Die1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Die2 = (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)
Die3 = (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)
Die4 = (4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24)

n = 100

allpos = list(product(range(n), product(Die1, Die2, Die3, Die4)))

with Pool() as p:
        success = p.map(flippo, allpos)

print(round(sum(success)/1296,2),"% with", \
      Die1, Die2, Die3, Die4)
```

You will have to change first few lines of your `fliipo(Q)` function to assign a, b, c, d, r properly,

```
def flippo(Q): # return 1 if flippo is solvable, if not return 0
    r, (a, b, c, d) = Q    
    # Instead of
    #a = Q[0]
    #b = Q[1]
    #c = Q[2]
    #d = Q[3]
    #r = Q[4]
```

I would consider rewriting the program using numpy if you want more speed.
https://numpy.org/

Edit: *On my quad-core Intel i5-6400, it took 117 seconds for n=100 (129600 cases)*

Comment: Great idea! However, I haven't been able to reproduce this code for myself - waiting for over 10 minutes still doesn't get me an output. I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/vUqHcE0j). What should the code actually be and why?

Comment: @Lance Yes. I am not sure, what CPU does your computer have? I tested the code on computer running **Linux** with a **Intel Core-i5-6400**. This may sound stupid but, try running the script on another computer, preferably with more cores and Linux distro like Ubuntu installed.

Comment: @Lance You could also try opening the task manager and setting python processes to high priority.

Comment: I was using **Spyder** (Windows 10) with Intel Core i5-8265U. For me, putting the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard did the trick: running the [improved code](https://pastebin.com/sPV8pped) took about 170 seconds. (I don't think setting the python processes to high priority affected anything, though)

Comment: You also mentioned NumPy to rewrite my programme with. How would that work? And would NumPy also tackle my problem at its core (if so, how)? (As your answer was a bit irrelevant but still a great suggestion to speed up the programme nonetheless) After googling a bit, it seems that numpy is all about array programming. How would that replace my nested loops in `flippo(Q)` (`u1`, `u2`, u3` and perhaps even `elt`)

Comment: @Lance I did not read your `flippo(Q)` function (also have no clue what you are trying to simulate/calculate), I am not sure if it could rewritten in numpy, but if you can it would speed up your code by a LOT (It may even just finish in few seconds). Numpy is a C library, it would run a lot faster than programs written in pure python with multiprocessing. Also Numpy uses threads instead of processes, so there is less overhead in communication between the threads/processes.

Comment: @Lance  The process of converting loops into array calculations is called *vectorization*. Google around, see if you can "vectorize" your code. It would be worth it if you can for the speed.

Comment: @Lance If you found the answer useful, please click om the 'tick mark', let others know the solution worked.